# GridLayoutManager is not showing all the elements in Android

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

I have set up a GridLayoutManager with a span of 2 and ideally,it should show my elements in 2 columns but the output shows only one element.

Below is the code:

**Adapter**

```
    public class MemoriesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MemoriesAdapter.MemoriesViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "MemoriesAdapter";
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private final List<List<String>> titleList;
    private final List<List<StorageReference>> imageList;

    public MemoriesAdapter(Context context, List<List<String>> titleList, List<List<StorageReference>> imageList) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.titleList = titleList;
        this.imageList = imageList;
        Log.d(TAG, "Constructor ");
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MemoriesAdapter.MemoriesViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.memories_cards, parent, false);
        MemoriesAdapter.MemoriesViewHolder viewHolder = new MemoriesAdapter.MemoriesViewHolder(view);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder");
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MemoriesAdapter.MemoriesViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (!(titleList.isEmpty() || imageList.isEmpty())) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Lists are not empty, proceeding.");

            String title = String.valueOf(titleList.get(position));
            holder.title.setText(title);
            // TODO: get storage ref into the imageview
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return titleList.size();
    }

    public class MemoriesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private ImageView image;
        private TextView title;

        private ImageView image2;
        private TextView title2;

        public MemoriesViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Log.d(TAG, "ViewHolder");
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.memory_image_one);
            title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.memory_title);
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
memoriesViewModel.getTitleList().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), titList -> {
            titleList.add(titList);
            memoriesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Log.d(TAG, "Memories Frag " + titleList);
        });

GridLayoutManager manager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 2);
        memoryRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        memoryRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        memoryRecyclerView.setAdapter(memoriesAdapter);
```

**item_layout**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/memory_dashboard_card"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:background="@drawable/memories_card_yellow"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/memory_image_one"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/unicorn"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/memory_title"
            android:layout_width="108dp"
            android:layout_height="21dp"
            android:text="My first date was epic"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/memory_image_one" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**layout**

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/memories_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:spanCount="2"
        tools:listitem="@layout/memories_cards" />
```

Comment if you want more code or edit if I have given any unnecessary details

**Thank You!**

**EDIT:** I have added the entire adapter and I am removing the layout files.

Comment: in card_view did you set width and height of the views??

Comment: yes I did set the height and the width

Comment: show your complete adapter and item layout

Comment: I have done the changes.

Comment: try to use StaggeredGridLayoutManager layoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

Comment: and for testing change the android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp" to wrap_content

Comment: thanks a lot, I will try it, and get back to you.

Comment: I am sorry but no changes...

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kinda late but i had the same exact problem and to fix it make sure that the value of layout_width and layout_height is match_parent, i'm talking about the xml layout that you used in your recyclerview adapter, hope you got it fixed.